# Proving greedy algorithm with exchange argument

Tags: compare, pseudocode, greedy

So I have to write a greedy algorithm that given a linked list or array of pairs (t_i, w_i), I have to produce a schedule that generates the maximum amount of money within time T. t_i would be the maximum number of hours that can worked for that job, w_i would be the wage in dollars per hour and T would be the maximum number of hours that person is willing to work per week. Jobs don't need to be worked until t_i, as the worker can choose to switch jobs early and get paid for each hour they worked.

So I wrote a greedy algorithm where you just get the job with the highest wage per hour and work that job for as long as you can, then get the job with the second wage per hour and work that job for as long as you can and so on till you work T hours.

I am now being asked to use an exchange argument to prove that my pseudocode produces an optimal schedule. In my opinion, my pseudocode solution is already the optimal schedule, so what what I compare it to then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the idea of the demonstration without writting it entirely.

You need to take an optimal solution **S**. You can tell that this solution can grant **x** $, where **x** is the maximum money you can make.

Then you take your solution **G** witch is greedy.

Now you say the first job you chose in **G**, this job is **j1** and the time spent is **t1**. There is two possibility, either **j1** is in **S** or it's not. If it's not by replacing one job in **S** by **j1** you get a better solution (or at least as good) BUT **S** is optimal so you can conclude that **j1** is in **S**. You can do the same kind of reasoning to prove that the time associed with **j1** in **S** is **t1**.

Then you do that for every element. And you'll conclude that the amount of money **x** earned is the same in **G** and in **S**. So **G** is optimal